# what is the radius of convergence for the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$

Tags: complex-analysis

let $f$ be  an  analytic  fuction such that

$f(z) =1+2z + 3z^2 +....$ for $|z| <1$

define  a sequence of real numbers  $a_0 , a_1 , a_2 ...$ by

$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n(z+2)^n$

what is the  radius of convergence for the  series  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n?$

**My attempt** :$f(z) =1+2z + 3z^2 +....=\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}$

so $f(z)$ has  poles  at $z=1$  of order  $2$

Therefore  the  radius of  convergence  is  the  distance from $-2$ to the  closest of these  poles

$\implies |-2-1 +0i|=\sqrt{3}$

Radius of  convergence $R= \sqrt{3}$

Is my answer correct or incorrect?

Comment: $|-2-1 +0i|=\sqrt{3}$ ?? the rest looks good

Comment: Complex modulus @Conrad The modulus of a complex number is the square root of the sum of the squares of the real part and the imaginary part of the complex number

Comment: okay @Conrad Got it

Comment: In other words, $R = \sqrt{3^2} =3$ @Conrad Am i right ?

Comment: yes - or just simply $R=|-3|=3$ as the imaginary part is $0$

Comment: In your second equation, where you set f(z) equal to an infinite summation: For which z are you assuming this equality holds? (All z with |z| < 1, or perhaps some other set?)

Comment: @DanAsimov $|z| <1$